# Proving existence of roots

Tags: dynamical-systems, roots, fixed-point-theorems, chaos-theory

I have the following arbitrary function which is the result of solving an iterative map for any period two fixed points (ie. for $g(x_n) = x_{n+1}$, I am trying to find $k$-values for which g(g(x)) = x) where $T,B,k \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$:
$$T^k x^{k^2-k} - (B-x^k)^{k-1} - T(T-1)(B-x^k)^{k-2}x^k = 0$$
and I am trying to identify the $k$ values for which 2-period bifurcation occurs. In simulation, we have a stable fixed point with dampened oscillations to this point for $k < 2$, and period doubling followed by chaos as $k$ increases past 2. We additionally always have a fixed point at $$x = \left(\frac{B}{T+1}\right)^{1/k}$$
which is stable for $0 < k < 2$. How should I proceed with finding proving this bifurcation?

Comment: Your conjecture is not true: see [this example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ssvzgwamwn) for instance. Where is this coming from? (Let me also point out that this is not exactly a polynomial - typically one requires integer exponents.)

Comment: Yea so this is derivate from an iterative map where I am trying to demonstrate the existence of period two cycles ie if $g(x_n) = x_{n+1}$, I am trying to prove for which values of the parameter $k$ that we can have $g(g(x)) = x$. Your counterexample is definitely interesting, thank you. Any advice with the given context?

Comment: I think you should add this motivation to your post. It sounds like you may have better luck tagging this with [dynamical-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamical-systems), which I think is a better tag than linear algebra or polynomials (there's no linear algebra or polynomials here, except for special values of $k$).

Comment: Updated the tags and problem statement, thanks!